# webpack (with sass-loader) - scss file @import does not recognize resolve alias

Tags: sass, webpack, autoprefixer, sass-loader

My project structure:

```
webpack.config.js
app--

   --> src
   ---->> components
   ------>>> myComponent.js
   ------>>> myComponent.scss

   --> styles
   ---->> variables.scss
```

In webpack.config module.exports:

```
...
resolve: {
    alias: {
       styles: path.join(__dirname, 'app/styles') 
   }
}
```

In my file - myComponent.scss:

```
@import "styles/variables";
```

I am getting this error when building bundle.js:

```
Module build failed:
@import "styles/variables";
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: styles/variables
```

How can I @import aliases in sass files?

Comment: Perhaps adding information about the directory structure of the project, especially the files mentioned, would help.

Comment: added project structure to question

Comment: A very quick observation - may be irrelevant: the directory `styles` is included both in `alias.styles` as `path.join(..., 'app/styles')` and in the import as `@import "styles/variables"`. It may need to be `@import "variables"`.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos That is the way that an alias is defined and used in webpack - https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Tarlen - nope, still no solution. currently I just use the relative path in the sass file import, without referring to the alias..

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I was able to use, on a stylesheet, an alias that I defined in webpack by using the following:

```
@import '~alias/variables';
```

just by prefixing the alias with `~` did the trick for me, as suggested by documentation in [here](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader#imports)

Comment: This works great but how do you get your editor to stop complaining about it. Obvisouly ~alias directory doesn't exist.

Comment: @tkiethanom for you and anyone else who comes across this answer, see CrocoDillon's answer. Basically, if your config file looks exactly the same as his, you would use: `@import '~styles/variables';`

Comment: @tkiethanom Not sure about other editors, but IntelliJ/PhpStorm will use webpack.config.js to resolve imports, so it recognizes aliases.

Comment: Using `~` is **deprecated** and can be removed from your code.

Answer (score 9):

Another fix related to this subject, remove `.scss`

```
@import '~scss/common.scss';
```

should be

```
@import '~scss/common';
```

Comment: 2018 and stuck at this. I'm using @material packages and they are all without tilde character!! so sass-loader gets stuck at subsequent imports. Tried adding an alias for `@material` and point to `path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@material')` with no luck. Asked a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368639/vue-and-webpack-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-material-ripple-commo

Answer (score 3):

Since your `webpack.config.js` file is already in the `/app` folder, shouldn’t the alias be:

```
resolve: {
   alias: {
       styles: path.join(__dirname, 'styles') 
   }
}
```

?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. Webpack.config is on the top level dir, edited question accordingly

Comment: Okay, already thought that’d be too easy. I’d have commented instead of answered but not enough rep.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the dependency is a node module, therefore I can import it like this:

`@import '~node-module-name/variables';`

And when using the actual node module dir name, my editor (PhpStorm) is not showing unresolved path error anymore (the problem which @tkiethanom mentioned). It looks like I need to specify alias in webpack config if I want to use sass style imports (e.g. `my-package/colors` instead of `my-package/_colors.scss`), and it seems it doesn't matter what is the name of that alias, as long as I use node module directory name