# Webpack and Aliases within scss @import

Tags: webpack, sass, webpack-2

Given below project structure:

```
|- SRC
|-- COMMON
|---- SCSS
|------ GLOBAL.scss
|------ VARIABLES.json (scss colors in json structure)
|-- PAGES
|---- COMPONENTS
|------ COMPONENT A
|-------- SCSS
|---------- componentA.scss
|------ COMPONENT B
|-------- SCSS
|---------- componentB.scss
```

I want to `@import global.scss` file into the single component scss files. I don't want to use relative paths, because components structure may have different nesting.

Currently I'm using Webpack Aliases:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    common: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/common/')
  }
}
```

and I'm using `@import 'common/scss/global.scss';` and `@import 'common/scss/variables.json'` and it's not working.

- Module build failed
- File to import not found or unreadable.

PS. Using json-loader, sass-loader etc.

Could you please help to find working solution of how to import JSON and SCSS without using relative '../../../../../' paths?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [webpack (with sass-loader) - scss file @import does not recognize resolve alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717203/webpack-with-sass-loader-scss-file-import-does-not-recognize-resolve-alias)

Answer (score 2):

Sass has no special syntax for relative paths, so your import is equivalent to:

```
@import './common/scss/global.scss';
```

To inform webpack that it should be resolved as a module you can start the path with `~` and your alias will be applied correctly. See also [`sass-loader` imports](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#imports).

```
@import '~common/scss/global.scss';
```