# WebStorm cannot resolve scss imports

Tags: vue.js, intellij-idea, sass, webstorm

WebStorm 2019.2 / Vue-CLI

App.vue file with scss imports:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
@import '@/assets/scss/app.scss';
</style>
```

None of the scss files are successfully resolved:

[image]

I already tried to set my src folder as resource root - no effect. I thought WS is working well with anything frontend-related out of the box.. because VSCode does. Is it a bug? Or i am doing something wrong.

**UPDATE 1**

I went to Preferences > Language & Frameworks / JavaScript / Webpack and set path to /Users/alexanderkim/Sites/vueproject/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/webpack.config.js, still it doesn't see an alias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try prefixing the import path with tilda:

```
@import '~@/assets/scss/app.scss';
```

this is a sass-loader feature that works both for `node_modules` and webpack aliases.
See  https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#imports, [webpack (with sass-loader) - scss file @import does not recognize resolve alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717203/webpack-with-sass-loader-scss-file-import-does-not-recognize-resolve-alias)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to set your path with "~" to node-modules?
And, for using "@" alias you should set up it in your webpack.config
[see here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/)

Comment: Tilda works for `node_modules`, but "@" alias is setup in vue-cli tool.